# Mount partitions/images with Linux filesystems

Tags: partition, unix, filesystem, mount

I've created a local image of the drive of a hosted VPS by using `dd` over `ssh` (`ssh user@123.45.67.89 "dd if=/dev/vda " | dd of=/Volumes/Backup/droplet.img`).

`mount` shows that macOS supports `afs`, `hfs`, `exfat`, et cetera... but not any version of the Extended File System.

I'm running Sierra (10.12.6); what's the best way to mount this image and gain read/write access to its file system? Fuse-based solutions suggested in other posts appear deprecated and no longer suggested or maintained.

Comment: Personally, what I would do is create a headless (Linux) VM and share the mount over NFS

Comment: That's not a bad idea. I'll go this route if using tools within [e2fsprogs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E2fsprogs) doesn't work.